# Exception class jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader cannot be cast to class java.net.URLClassLoader

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I don't understand how to fix it, first time i see mistake like this.
i downland this from github https://github.com/nikishubin/Notebook but its does not work

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Options -Xverify:none and -noverify were deprecated in JDK 13 and will likely be removed in a future release.
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader cannot be cast to class java.net.URLClassLoader (jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader and java.net.URLClassLoader are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.DefaultRestartInitializer.getUrls(DefaultRestartInitializer.java:93)
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.DefaultRestartInitializer.getInitialUrls(DefaultRestartInitializer.java:56)
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter.<init>(Restarter.java:140)
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter.initialize(Restarter.java:546)
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartApplicationListener.onApplicationStartingEvent(RestartApplicationListener.java:67)
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(RestartApplicationListener.java:45)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:122)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.starting(EventPublishingRunListener.java:69)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.starting(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:48)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:292)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
        at org.surplus.radolf.Notebook.NotebookApplication.main(NotebookApplication.java:10)
    
    Process finished with exit code 1
```

my main class

```
package org.surplus.radolf.Notebook;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;


@SpringBootApplication
public class NotebookApplication  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(NotebookApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: The system/application class loader used to be an implementation of `URLClassLoader` back in Java 8. However, that changed in Java 9 to a private (i.e. internal) implementation and is no longer an instance of `URLClassLoader`. It looks like the version of Spring Boot you're using is not compatible with this change (i.e. it assumes the system/application class loader is an instance of `URLClassLoader`). Either use a more recent version of Spring Boot if one exists or use Java 8 to run the application.

Answer (score 1):

From the pom file its noted that java 1.8 is refered can you can you please check java 1.8 is in your system path varibale or later version. if later please use 1.8 and try to run the program.

Answer (score 0):

If Java is 1.8, then check parent should match the release of the STS tools you ar using (i.e.)      Groupid and artifact and version

Comment: If Java is 1.8, then check parent should match the release of the STS tools you are using (i.e.)  PARENT  Groupid and artifact and version  /PARENT

Answer (score -2):

An alternative to installing Java 8 is to use your IDE's built in JDK.

In InteliJ, you can go to **Tools** tab:

[Click on 'Edit Configurations'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKgIy.png)

[And select java 8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uzjxp.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).